# how to put a section in my page magento

Tags: php, magento, menu, navigationbar, sections

I am new to magento and am trying to make a menu bar.
But I do not know how.
I watched tutorials but what I do does not work (nothing appears on my homepage).

Could someonehelp me?

Comment: Add the category in back end, you will get the navigation menu

Comment: Add subcategory to 'Default category'. Switch 'include in navigation menu' to 'yes'. Determine what to show on this page: static block or products. If static block - choose which one.

Comment: thanks for answer , zhartaunik i do that  but nothing appear in my page

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6r54u0 http://prntscr.com/6r54ym http://prntscr.com/6r5550

Answer (score 1):

To create basic magento navigation menu, create new category under your root catalog category in "All store views" (in Catalog->Manage Categories). Note that you need to first click the root catalog and then click the "add sub-category" when the root catalog is highlighted.

After that, check that you have both "is Active" and "Include in navigation menu" set as Yes. Save the category, and check your home page.

If the menu bar isn't shown, then you might have cache enabled. To refresh cache, go to System->Cache Management. Easiest way of refreshing the caches is to just click both "Flush Magento Cache" and "Flush Cache Storage".

If you still have trouble seeing the navigation bar then your browser might also have cached version of the page. Try resetting the browser cache or check the page on different browser.

Also, if you have installed some theme for your magento, then I suggest on trying to get the categories to show on the basic magento theme first.